# Gradle jacoco code coverage - Then publish/show in Jenkins

Tags: unit-testing, tomcat, gradle, code-coverage, jacoco

I'm trying to setup code coverage for a Java application project.

Project name     : NewApp

Project structure:

- src/java/** (source code)
- src/java-test (unit tests - Jnuit)
- test/it-test (integration test)
- test/at-tests (acceptance tests)
- tomcat/* (contain tomcat start/stop scripts)
- xx/.. etc folders which are required for a usual application.

Gradle version   : 1.6

Environment      : Linux

I have a running gradle build script that fetches application (NewApp) dependencies (i.e. service jars used by the app for build process) from a build artifact repository (artifactory/maven for ex), and builds the app.

Now at this point, I wanted to get code coverage using JaCoCo plugin for my NewApp application project.

I followed the documentation per Gradle/Jacoco but it doesn't seems to create any reports/... folder for jacoco etc where I can find what Jacoco coverage report did.

My questions:
1. For getting code coverage using Unit tests (Junit), I assume all I have to do is the following and it will NOT require me to start/stop the tomcat before running unit test (test task i.e. "gradle test") to get code coverage for/via using unit tests. Please advise/correct. The code (just for Gradle jacoco unit test part) - I'm using is:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

test {
      include 'src/java-test/**'
}

jacocoTestReport {
    group = "reporting"
    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports after running tests."
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        html.enabled true
        csv.enabled false
    }
    //classDirectories = fileTree(dir: 'build/classes/main', include: 'com/thc/**')
    //sourceDirectories = fileTree(dir: 'scr/java', include: 'com/thc/**')
    additionalSourceDirs = files(sourceSets.main.allJava.srcDirs)
}
```

and for Integration tests:

```
task integrationTest(type: Test) {
        include 'test/java/**'
}
```

As jacocoTestReport is depends upon test task(s), thus they will be called first and then finally jacocoTestReport will report what it found for the code coverage.

1. For getting code coverage for integration tests, I assume I must start tomcat first (i.e. before running / calling test target for integration tests), then call "gradle integrationTest" or "gradle test" task and then stop tomcat -- to get the code coverage report. From other blog posts I also found that one should setup JAVA_OPTS variable to assign jacoco agent before tomcat starts.

for ex: setting JAVA_OPTS variable like:

```
export JACOCO="-Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -javaagent:/production/jenkinsAKS/jobs/NewApp/workspace/jacoco-0.6.3.201306030806/lib/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=/production/jenkinsAKS/jobs/NewApp/workspace/jacoco/jacoco.exec,append=true,includes=*"
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS $JACOCO"
```

1. Being new to Gradle/groovy - I'm not sure what code should I write within build.gradle (build script) to get the above Integration/Unit tests working if it involves start/stop of tomcat. If someone can provide a sample script to do that, I'll try.
2. I'm not getting any code coverage right now, when I publish Jacoco code coverage in Jenkins (using Jenkins post build action for publishing Jacoco reports). Jenkins build dashboard shows 0% for code coverage (i.e. bars showing all red color, no green for actual code coverage).

Need your advice to get some traction on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working.

Gradle 1.7
 - download the .zip which contains the binaries/src and documentation.
 - Go to folder: if you unzip the above .zip at C:\gradle-1.7
 C:\gradle-1.7\samples\testing\jacoco\quickstart

- Run:
  gradle build jacocoTestReport
- You’ll see a new folder “build” after the build.
  – folder jacoco gets created with classdumps and .exec if only build task is called.
  – folder jacoco and jacocoHtml gets created – if both build jacocoTestReport is called

have fun.

I also saw that it’s better to include:

the following section in build.gradle

```
/////
 tasks.withType(Compile) {
 options.debug = true
 options.compilerArgs = ["-g"]
 }
 ////
```

Comment: Other good links: http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/gradle_1_6_jacoco_in_multi_module_build

Answer (score 0):

1. Question : I assume that your unit tests doesn't depend on tomcat. In this case, you're right, you must not start tomcat upfront.

   To create the coverage report you need to execute

   ```
   gradle jacocoTestReport
   ```

   without `jacocoTestReport` gradle won't trigger jacoco to generate the reports.

   One additional thing, regarding to your snippet. I assume that you have changed the the default main sourceset to `source/java`. in this case you don't have to set the `additionalSourceDirs`.
2. Integration tests : Yes, you need to start tomcat first, or at least you have to ensure that tomcat is running. You should have a look into Gradle 1.7. It has a new task ordering rule called `finalizedBy`

   With this you could do something like

   ```
   task integrationtests(type: Test) {
     dependsOn startTomcat
     finalizedBy stopTomcat
   }
   ```

   where start/stopTomcat are custom tasks.If you have to stay on Gradle 1.6 you have to build a `dependsOn` chain:

   ```
   stopTomcat -dependsOn-> integrationtests -dependsOn-> startTomcat
   ```

   I assume that the blog article is right, I don't have any experience with that.
3. Starting/Stoping Tomcat : You could do it in a way like this

   ```
   task startTomcat() << {
     def tomcatStartScript = "${project.rootDir}/tomcat/startScript"
     tomcatStartScript.execute()
   }
   ```

   The stop script can be written in a similiar way. (Some in from Groovy doc : [Executing](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Executing+External+Processes+From+Groovy))
4. Jenkins & Jacoco : Should be fixed when executing `jacocoTestReport`

Comment: I'll give this a try. Apart from that, I also need to make sure that we have tests (specially integration ones) otherwise report will still show 0% on few. Thus, there should be unit / integration tests which I'll make sure they exist in the project. Thanks a lot Pete for your explanation.

Comment: As I'm not using the cargo / gradle built/provided tomcat plugin, and wanted the "tomcat" folder that reside in my source code to start the instance on the server, I used this link to start / stop tomcat, but it starting the tomcat with/without & (run in background) just hangs and I never reach at intergrationTest task. if I manually kill the tomcat running instance, then it proceeds, fails the tests (as tomcat is killed/not available) and stopTomcat_local task fails too. I created the following dependency struct: stopTomcatLocal --> depends on integrationTest --> depends upon startTomcatLocal