# Jacoco 0% Code Coverage

Tags: jenkins, gradle, sonarqube, jacoco, sonarqube-scan

My Code Coverage in Sonar is showing 0% which isn't true as I do have Unit Tests.

**Gradle**

```
sonarqube {
  properties {
    property "sonar.binaries", "build/intermediates/classes/release"
    property "sonar.java.binaries", "build/intermediates/classes/release"
    property "sonar.java.test.binaries", "build/intermediates/classes/test/release"
    property "sonar.sources", "src"
    property "sonar.junit.reportsPath", "build/reports/tests/release"
    property "sonar.java.junit.reportsPath", "build/reports/tests/release"
    property "sonar.android.lint.report", "build/outputs/lint-results.xml"
    property "sonar.jacoco.reportPath", "${project.buildDir}/jacoco/testReleaseUnitTest.exec"
  }
}
```

When I open up the `index.html` inside `build/reports/tests/release` then I *can* see successful unit tests.

I run `sonarqube` as a `gradle task` within my Jenkins environment. My SonarQube instance shows `Code Smells` and everything but for `code coverage`, it shows **0%**.

**Update**

I do get an `index.html` created for the Code Coverage but that's all showing 0% too:

`app/build/reports/jacoco/jacocoTestDebugUnitTestReport/html/index.html`

**Update**

Still getting 0% but this is what I have so far:

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }
    }

    jacoco {
        version "0.7.8.201607051106"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by using [this](https://github.com/vanniktech/gradle-android-junit-jacoco-plugin) plugin. The problem as I see it was that Jacoco was trying to look for Instrumentation Tests `androidTests` and not Unit Tests `tests`. The plugin which I used made sure that it ran the tests before hand, created a report based on the tests AND make Jacoco point to those tests.

Answer (score 2):

Excerpt from [SonarQube Documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project):

> The Java Plugin reuses reports; it does not generate them. So before trying to configure your analysis to import these reports, make sure they are correctly generated and non-empty.

Since you don't seem to be using the [Gradle Jacoco plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html), SonarQube is probably reporting that 0% because you have not generated a report.  You will need to add Jacoco to your build and ensure that you have fed SonarQube the path of the generated report (`sonar.jacoco.reportPath`) so it can read it.

To add Jacoco to your project, you will need to add the following to `build.gradle`:

```
//...
apply plugin: "jacoco"
//...
jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.6.201602180812"
    //Note: unless "reportsDir" is set here, default is “$buildDir/reports/jacoco”
}
```

You  will also need to ensure the following: First of all, you need to ensure the `jacocoTestReport` task is being executed (either by adding it to tasks yourself; or by adding the task to your gradle invocation).  Secondly, you need to make sure that SonarQube is looking in the correct location for the test report by setting `sonar.jacoco.reportPath` to point to your `/reports/jacoco` directory (it's defaulting to `target/jacoco.exec`, so it won't find a report on default settings).

Comment: Can you give an example of what you exactly mean by "add Jacoco to your build" please?

Comment: Added build script and SonarQube details to answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18106492/gradle-jacoco-code-coverage-then-publish-show-in-jenkins